# php variables with multiple images fading

Tags: php

Here is what I am working with:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="span 6">
<?php for ($i=1; $i<=100; $i++) { ?>
  <div id="cf7_<?=$i?>" class="shadow">
      <img class='opaque' src="/img/imgA<?=$i?>.jpg" />
      <img src="/img/imgB<?=$i?>.jpg" />
      <img src="/img/imgC<?=$i?>.jpg" />
      <img src="/img/imgD<?=$i?>.jpg" />
  </div>
  <?php } ?>
  <p id="cf7_controls">
      <span class="selected">Image 1</span>
      <span>Image 2</span>
      <span>Image 3</span>
      <span>Image 4</span>
  </p>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#cf7_controls").on('click', 'span', function() {
    $("#cf7_<?=$i?> img").removeClass("opaque");
    var newImage = $(this).index();
    $("#cf7_<?=$i?> img").eq(newImage).addClass("opaque");
    $("#cf7_controls span").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
    });
});
</script>

<style>
p#cf7_controls {
  text-align:center;
}
#cf7_controls span {
  padding-right:2em;
  cursor:pointer;
}
#cf7_<?=$i?> {
  position:relative;
  height:281px;
  width:450px;
  margin:0 auto 10px;
}
#cf7_<?=$i?> img {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  opacity:0;
  -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}

#cf7_<?=$i?> img.opaque {
  opacity:1;
  -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=1);
}
</style>
```

I pulled this code from http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/#cfimg7 
    and [Need helping getting this string of Javascript to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18178073/need-helping-getting-this-string-of-javascript-to-work)
It works well when there are a few images, i.e. a few divs with id='cf7'.
However, when there are over one hundred images, i.e. 100+ images with id='cf7', 
I think php or javascript variables should be inserted in the id='cf7', and corresponding javascript and css stylesheet.
How can I do it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is. What do you want to achieve? Where are you struggling? You mention PHP, so can you please write your PHP code?

Comment: if there are multiple divs: <div id='cf7_01'>...</div><div id='cf7_02'>...</div><div id='cf7_03'>...</div>......<div id='cf7_100'>...</div>, the ids should be variables, and the variables also should be inserted and worked in the javascript and css stylesheet.

Comment: I understand. Note that the `<style>` tag is not allowed in the `<body>`. Some browsers allow it anyway, some do not.

Comment: Then how can I achieve it? How can I set php variables with css? Is it possible: echo '<style>#cf7_<?=$i?> {... ...} </style>';

Comment: Don't use any PHP in your stylesheets. It is ugly, and it is never required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, you want to be able to have multiple cross fading image elements on a page, so you need different IDs. But I don't think this for loop does what it is supposed to do.

First, **don't mess in your stylesheet with PHP**. The stylesheet should be in a different file or at least in the `<head>`. There are actually browsers that ignore stylesheets that are outside the `<head>`.

If you need multiple instances of `#cf7`, you should use a **class** and use this class in the stylesheet. Additionally, you need an id to identify the element via javascript.

Don't forget to put the controls and the javascript in the loop! Otherwise, these will only appear once on the page. Every image needs a corresponding control.

However, I suggest to use a function here:

```
<?php

function showCrossFadingImages($id, $image_array) {
  echo "<div id='cf7_$id' class='cf7 shadow'>";

  $opaque = 'class="opaque"';
  foreach ($image_array as $img) {
    echo "<img src='/img/$img' $opaque />";
    $opaque = ''; // don't show this after the first iteration
  }

  echo '</div>';

  echo "<div id='cf7_controls_$id' class='cf7_controls'>";

  $selected = 'class="selected"';
  foreach ($image_array as $i => $img) {
    echo "<span $selected>Image $i</span>";
    $selected = ''; // don't show this after the first iteration
  }

  echo '</div>';

  echo "<script>
        \$(document).ready(function() {
          \$('#cf7_controls_$id').on('click', 'span', function() {
            \$('#cf7_$id img').removeClass('opaque');
            var newImage = \$(this).index();
            \$('#cf7_$id img').eq(newImage).addClass('opaque');
            \$('#cf7_controls_$id span').removeClass('selected');
            \$(this).addClass('selected');
          });
        });
        </script>";
}
```

Now you can call this function:

```php
showCrossFadingImages(1, array("Turtle.jpg", "Rainbow_Worm.jpg", "Birdman.jpg"));
```

I haven't tested it, but it should work.

EDIT: The stylesheet should now have the following selectors:

```css
p.cf7_controls

.cf7_controls span

.cf7

.cf7 img

.cf7 img.opaque
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer!! I will try it.